# How to change propagation function in keras?

Tags: r, neural-network, keras

it possible to change the propagation function or the parameters in the keras framework? i didn't find something in the documentation. Which one is used, is it the simplest one "Input ij = aj*wij"?

In the literature i can find different functions, e.g.

[image: Different functions]

But which one is used by Keras?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by propagation function. Can you give an example of what it is that you want to change? Maybe a sample model etc.

Comment: i mean the Input variables. Wikipedia says: "The propagation function computes the input  to the neuron  from the outputs  of predecessor neurons and typically has the form"
I also edited my post, because in the literature/books i found different functions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are reading something highly theoretical. The answer depends on the layer you use. The normal dense (fully connected) layer uses sum. Pooling layers perform max or average. Other layers like RNNs have much more complex logic that can include operations that are not even on your list. And the answer to the first question: no you can't change it. In the standard keras layers you can change the arguments but that doesn't include the propagation function. [More about this.](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense) Nevertheless you can create your own layer and change the code.